# Github action could not open input file: artisan

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a Github action/workflow for my Laravel project service. I used the template given by Github action for my Laravel project which include a generated key which calls for PHP artisan. However, when the action is running, I always get an error in my generated key, it says it couldn't find an input `file: artisan no file or directory`.

I've been spending weeks on this and there's no progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting that error message is because the php artisan command is not executed in proper directory. You have to make it so that it runs inside of the project folder and not above it.

So if you have a project called /laravel-project

You must get inside that directory and run `php artisan key:generate`

and not like this

```
mkdir laravel-project
php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: Thank you so much @lewis4u for the inspiration! I search around and apparently I did not set a default working-directory properly. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help ;)